# Five tyres over $40000$ kilometres

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

The five tyres of a car (four road tyres and one spare) were used equally in a journey of $40,000~\text{km}$. The number of kilometres of use of each tyre was

a. $40000$
b. $10000$
c. $32000$
d. $8000$

This is what I tried. I just want to know is my approach is correct or not. Or is there any better method to solve this type of question?

Total kilometers travelled by $4$ tyres $= 40000 \cdot 4 = 160,000$.
 
This has to be shared by $5$ tyres.
So each tyre capacity $= \frac{160,000}{5} = 32,000$.
 
After we travel $32,000~\text{km}$, we are left with $4$ worn tyres and one new tyre. But if the tyres are rotated properly after each $8000~\text{km}$,

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: On average a tyre is in use 80% of the time (4 tyres are used out of 5). So what do you think the answer might be?

Comment: @5xum updated question with my attempt to it and thanks for tips and suggestion for better usability of the site

Comment: Your answer is correct.  I assume you meant to say that if the tyres are rotated properly after each $8000~\text{km}$ that each tyre will travel $32,000~\text{km}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that every tire, in order to have equal use, had to at least once have been in the spare tire compartment. This means that there were 5 journeys in between the tire changes. Each journey was 8000km long (40,000/5). So, because each tire was on the road per journey segment except for 1, each tire was used a total of 32,000 times (8000x4)

Answer (score -1):

You will switch tires $4$ times so every tire has a chance to run. So you will be making $5$ lags, and so each lag will be $8000$. So each of the $5$ tires rests in a lag of $8000$. Or, each tire runs a total of $32000$